# Get all regex matches between two patterns and print them to file

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I've got a file with a bunch of long lines. I'd like to grab every group between two patterns and print them to a new file, one match per line. I could manage to do this with Python, but I'd prefer using just command line tools for this task. If there is no end pattern, I'd like to grab everything 'till the end of the line.

Something like:

```
input: 
xxSTART relevanttext xxEND something else xxSTART even more relevant

output:
relevanttext
even more relevant
```

Comment: So `START` and `END` both are within the same long line?

Comment: Yes! I used to have just one match per line, so I'd use `sed` to grab everything after `xxSTART`, but now the input data changed and I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF GNU grep is an option, you could pass the `-P` (perl-compatible regex) flag and use lookahead assertions, lookbehind assertions and non-greedy matches to pull out what you need

```
echo 'xxSTART relevanttext xxEND something else xxSTART even more relevant'  |\
grep -oP '(?<=START).*?(?=xxEND|$)'
relevanttext
even more relevant
```

Or as Stephane Chazelas suggests, use the nifty [\K](http://www.charlestonsw.com/perl-regular-expression-k-trick/) in place of the look-behind assertion

```
echo 'xxSTART relevanttext xxEND something else xxSTART even more relevant'  |\
grep -oP 'START\K.*?(?=xxEND|$)'
```

Comment: Or: `grep -oP 'START\K.*?(?=xxEND|$)'`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, that's a good point, added in. My version of GNU grep (2.5.1) doesn't support `\K` though

Comment: That's more down to the version of libpcre `grep` was linked against than the version of `grep` itself. `\K` was added in pcre 7.2 (2007) (feature from perl 5.10)